# Parse txt file to JSON, Only getting last record

Tags: python, parsing

I have a formatted text file, made up of outlook emails.

[image]
The `From:` indicates a new email.

I am trying to parse the From, the Subject (into multiple fields), and then read the rest of the content until the **next new email** indicated by a new From:

First I am trying to just brute force it, since this is a test for a Proof of concept, however, I am only getting the **last** email in the chain.

```
l = []
with open(r'transcripts.txt', 'r') as transcripts:

for line in transcripts:
    is_new_subject = line.lower().startswith('from')
    if is_new_subject:
        record = {}
        record['from'] = line.split(':')[1]
    for line in transcripts:

        if line.lower().startswith('subject'):
            subject = line.split(':')[1]
            record['subject'] = subject
            split_it = subject.split('.')
            record['show'] = split_it[0]
            record['air_date'] = split_it[1]
            record['hour'] = split_it[2]
            record['content'] = ""
            for line in transcripts:
                record['content'] += line
                is_new_subject = line.lower().startswith('from')
                if is_new_subject:
                    l.append(record)
                    break
with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(l, outfile, indent=4)
```

Any thoughts, I am going to start reworking it from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [Email Parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#parser-class-api) . This is very easy to use . For some reason this email didn't work with multi part email. So I have used the split function created by @Max Paymar. Thanks @Max Paymar.

```
import email
import re


def parse_emails_from_list(email_list):
    """returns a list of emails from an email list"""
    return re.compile("From:").split(email_list)

a=open('sampleEmail.txt','r')
email_list = parse_emails_from_list(a.read())

for E_mail in email_list:
    msg = email.message_from_string('From:'+E_mail)
    print msg['Subject']
    print msg['From']
    print msg.get_payload()
```

Comment: This greatly simplified things as opposed to needing loop logic. Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit hard to read, I think it would be much easier for you to debug it if you broke it up into functions. Also, I'd recommend using python's re library for this type of text processing, as it's far more flexible than just testing for static strings. For example:

```
import re

def parse_emails_from_list(email_list):
    """returns a list of emails from an email list"""
    return re.compile("From:").split(email_list)

def parse_email_details_from_email(email):
    """do some more processing here"""
    email = {}
    email['subject'] = #parse your email details here
    #...
    #...
    return email

if __name__ == "main":
    """main loop"""
    parsed_emails = []
    with open(r'transcripts.txt', 'r') as email_list:
        email_list = parse_emails_from_list(transcripts)
        [parsed_emails.append(parse_email_details_from_email(email)) for email in email_list]

    with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(parsed_emails, outfile, indent=4)
```

After looking through your code a bit more it's apparent that your loop logic is definitely where you are having issues.

Comment: This was great guidance, appreciate the input. The answer below leverages builtin email package I was unaware of, which made the whole task much easier. Thanks again